# How to output a QNetworkRequest to a raw Http request?

Tags: c++, qt, http-headers, qdebug, qnetworkrequest

For Debugging purposes, I would like to examine the `QNetworkRequest`s that I build and see if they are formatted correctly.

However, I do not see how to output them to a string format based upon their api.

How can I go about viewing the raw http request?

Comment: Can you please add an example request you create with QNetworkRequest and the output you'd like to see to your question?

Comment: Given [tag:http-headers] tag you're probably need [QNetworkRequest::rawHeaderList()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#rawHeaderList)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to debug your requests generally:

```
#include <QDebug>

void debugRequest(QNetworkRequest request, QByteArray data = QByteArray())
{
  qDebug() << request.url().toString(); //output the url
  const QList<QByteArray>& rawHeaderList(request.rawHeaderList());
  foreach (QByteArray rawHeader, rawHeaderList) { //traverse and output the header
    qDebug() << request.rawHeader(rawHeader);
  }
}
```